# oracle sql update rows using analytical functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with below data

```
PRODUCT_ID  ORDER_DATE  NEW_ORDER_DATE
1000       2007/09/15   NULL
1000       2007/09/17   Null
1000       2007/09/20   Null
1000       2007/09/23   Null
1000       2007/09/25   Null
1000       2007/09/27   Null
```

And i have to update new_order_date with data as below

```
PRODUCT_ID  ORDER_DATE  NEW_ORDER_DATE
1000       2007/09/15   2007/09/16
1000       2007/09/17   2007/09/19
1000       2007/09/20   2007/09/22
1000       2007/09/23   2007/09/24
1000       2007/09/25   2007/09/26
1000       2007/09/27   2100/01/01
```

As you can see the new_order_date is always computed based on the next row order_date for the same product_id using date - 1 and the last row is updated to a default date 2100/01/01. Could you please let me if there any function that i can use to achieve this

Comment: Your previous question **title** was more succinct. why did you change  it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LEAD` function and a correlated update.

```
UPDATE product p1
SET NEW_ORDER_DATE = (
        SELECT new_order_date
        FROM (
            SELECT PRODUCT_ID
                ,ORDER_DATE
                ,LEAD(ORDER_DATE, 1, DATE '2100-01-01' + 1) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY PRODUCT_ID ORDER BY ORDER_DATE
                    ) - 1 AS new_order_date
            FROM product
            ) p2
        WHERE p1.PRODUCT_ID = p2.product_id
            AND p1.ORDER_DATE = p2.ORDER_DATE
        );
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68b62/1)

Comment: Thank you Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
update product p
    set new_order_date = (select max(order_date) keep (dense_rank first order by order_date)
                          from product p2
                          where p2.product_id = p.product_id
                         );
```

This actually keeps the last value as `NULL`.  That is easily fixed using `coalesce()`:

```
update product p
    set new_order_date = (select coalesce(max(order_date) keep (dense_rank first order by order_date), date '2100-01-01')
                          from product p2
                          where p2.product_id = p.product_id
                         );
```